# how to popup my google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

google chrome extension:
i have added a context menu to the browser, how to I popup the popup.html on click on the context menu item ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send a request to a content script in a tab where the menu item was clicked. In the content script get popup.html url by calling `chrome.extension.getURL("popup.html")` and then display this url in a popup like you normally would.

Comment: Thanks, yes, but I do want create a "window" with the popup. Can't I pop it like how google chrome does it, at the top right of the current window ?

Comment: @Prakash There is `chrome.windows` module where you can create new windows, if that's what you need: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/windows.html

Comment: Yes I guess that is all that I can do. Which is load up extension in a new chrome window. thanks.